# markers move while pinch to zoom open layers and google maps

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers with Google Layer, and I have a strange behaviour about markers on the map.

On mobile, when doing a pinch to zoom on the map, the markers move and zoom as the pinch happens But when the pinch is finished,  the markers fall back to the right place and with their real size.

```
var map;
var markers_array=new Array();
var markers;
var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var markersJSON;


function initlize()
{

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
maxResolution: "auto",
zoomDuration:0,
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets", // the default
            {numZoomLevels: 20,transitionEffect:"resize"}
        ),

    ],
      center: new              OpenLayers.LonLat(parseFloat(markersJSON[0].lon),parseFloat(markersJSON[0].lat))
.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        // Google.v3 uses web mercator as projection, so we have to
        // transform our coordinates


    zoom: 12,
        controls: [
      new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
          dragPanOptions: {
              enableKinetic: true
          }
      }),
      new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()
      ]
});

function addMarker(lat,lng,id,map_icon)
 {



markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
//markers_array[id]=markers;
var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat,lng);
lonlat.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
map.addLayer(markers);
markers.id=id;
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(40,60);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('server_address'+map_icon, size, offset);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat,icon));
markers.events.register( 'touchstart', markers,clickMarker);
//markers_array[id]=markers;
}

function clickMarker(evt){
  //{some code here}
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying that they should not move as the pinch is happening? Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: no its like the map remains constant and only the markers are moving or they become big on pinch and on pinch release they resize back to their original form

Comment: Like zooming in this example, http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/markers.html, but for pinch? The map resizes instantly, and the markers afterwards?

Comment: something like this but in my case the map doesn't re-size instead it zooms in a level but the markers re-size.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. This sounds like correct behavior. The map zooms first, then the markers are redrawn at their original size in terms of pixels. Do you want the markers to get bigger/smaller, as you zoom in/out.

Comment: i have provided a video related to the issue please have a look https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xme7a9u8wih2am/15-07-2014-17-233.mp4

Comment: Thanks for video. That is more or less what I expected. Unfortunately, this is expected behavior in OL2, you will have to use OL3 to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenLayers 2, the vector features are not redraw until the zoom/move has finished. If you look at the code for moveTo in the [Map source](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js) you will see that all of the layers have their own moveTo event called, which actually redraws the vectors, see [Layer Vector source](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector.js). This is more obvious if you draw a large polygon and then drag it half of the screen, release the mouse, then drag it back on to the screen, and you will see it does not redraw until you release the mouse.

```
 if (inRange && layer.visibility) {
      layer.moveTo(bounds, zoomChanged, options.dragging);
      options.dragging || layer.events.triggerEvent(
      "moveend", {zoomChanged: zoomChanged}
       );
 }
```

In OpenLayers 3, the renderer is a bit more powerful, and vectors get updated while the map is zooming or panning. I created this [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/4/) to answer a different question, but you will see that the icons update immediately.

Note: I have tested only tested this on an Android phone and Linux desktop, but both work as expected.

**`Note: OpenLayers 3 is still in beta,`** so while it looks like it is going to be a very impressive rewrite with lots of new capabilities, I am not necessarily recommending it for production use right now.